# how to check duplicate files in airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

- I have incoming files in 'source-bucket'
- I archive files after processing into another bucket 'archive-bucket'
  in the current date-time folder.

eg:

- gs://archive-bucket/module1/2021-06-25/source_file_20210622.csv
- gs://archive-bucket/module1/2021-06-26/source_file_20210623.csv
- gs://archive-bucket/module1/2021-06-27/source_file_20210624.csv

Every time I process a file, I want to check if the file is already processed by checking the if it is present in the archive folder.

```
duplicate_check = GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor(
    task_id=f'detect_duplicate_{task_name}',
    bucket=ARCHIVE_BUCKET,
    prefix=f'module1/{DATE}/{source_file_name}')
```

This approach is only allowing to check for the particular date folder.
How to check if the 'source_file_<>.csv' is already present in the 'gs://archive-bucket/module1/`all the date folders`/'
even if the file is present in any date folder in the archive path, I need to fail further processing.
How can that be acheived?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can do it easily. You could probably play with "delimiter" parameter https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/920#issuecomment-230214336 to achieve something similar. Maybe you can even try to set delimiter to be your file name and look for "module1/" prefix. Not sure about efficiency of that though.

The problem is that GCS is NOT a filesystem with folders. The "/" is just convenience to treat it as directory and the UI allows you to "browse" it in similar way, but in fact the GCS object are not stored in subfolders - whole name of the object is the only identifier and there nothing like "folders" in  GCS. So you can only match the file names and matching by prefix is efficient. If you will have a lot of files, any other kind of matching might be slow.

What I recommend, maybe is to have a separate path. where you create empty objects corresponding to file names processsed. For example "processed/file.name" path. Without any structure. Then you could check for presence of the file name there. This will be rather efficient (but might not be atomic, depending how your processing looks like).

Answer (score 1):

From Your requirement what i understand is, you want to move files once they are processed from src bucket to another bucket and you want to make sure that file is moved to dest bucket successfully.

Best way to do it is,

1)Maintain a small sql table to insert file path which is processed into table as "Processed" and whenever state is processed move those files to dest bucket. From this table you can check always what all files are processed and moved to dest bucket.

and
2) another approach is

if task1=task to process files

task2=pass processed files to bashoperator

and using **gsutil** option you can move files easily and also check in
that script whether it is being pushed.